# Can Anyone Identify This Small Blue-Flowered Shrubby Plant?

Tags: cultivar

I have a small, blue-flowered, something growing under the Japonica in my garden in north Cymru and I need to know if anyone here can identify it.

The plant is low-growing and, left alone, will grow into a green, bushy, mound a foot or two high, happily spreading wherever it can. The flowers are a lovely deep blue and are popular with pollinators, *eg*: bees. Outside of that, it is hairy all over and fairly fragile with slender fibrous stems and glossy green, lanceolate, leaves and appears to like shady, damp, locations.

This may not be much to go on, but hopefully someone will be able to identify it, and you have my thanks in advance to all who try to.

[image: - unidentified blue-flowered small bushy plant -]
[image: - small blue flower of unknown bushy plant -]

Answer (score 1):

It's Lithodora diffusa, probably 'heavenly blue', though there's some confusion about the varietal names (there's a dark blue flowered one too), previously called Lithospermum. It's an alpine plant, likes neutral to acidic soil in part shade or full sun. https://www.gardentags.com/plant-encyclopedia/lithodora-diffusa-heavenly-blue-syn-lithospermum-diffusum-heavenly-blue-lithospermum-heavenly-blue/6145

Comment: Brilliant! - Thanks! - I can now safely transplant it knowing that if it dies on me this time (I thought I had lost it after splitting the main plant last year) I will be able to replace it.